# How do I convince Visual Studio I'm building a desktop app, not ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to import an app I built with .NET Core on Linux into Visual Studio, but it won't build, complaining that there's no output configured. When trying to set an output in the project properties, it only gives me the ASP.NET options.

How do I tell VS this is a desktop, and not a web project?

My project.json file follows, although from what I can tell, in Visual Studio, this seems to mainly be used for ASP projects? (Or at least, that's what all the documentation leads me to believe.) I'd like to keep this file working so it still builds in .NET Core.

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "configurations": {
    "Debug": {
      "compilationOptions": {
        "define": ["DEBUG", "TRACE"]
      }
    },
    "Release": {
      "compilationOptions": {
        "define": ["RELEASE", "TRACE"],
        "optimize": true
      }
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "ZWaveLib": "1.0.14",
        "YamlDotNet": "4.0.1-pre288",
        "NLog.Config": "4.3.10"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post your project.json file.

Comment: in VS we have 3 .NET Core project templates: console, library and ASP.NET. Which type you choose creating project?

Comment: I didn't create the project in Visual Studio, I originally created it with "dotnet new" on Linux, which is sort of the problem I'm having -- when I imported it into VS it just assumed it was an ASP.NET project.

Comment: then create console in VS and compare

Comment: Creating a console application does not create a project.json file, or any other file which is easily edited or compared.